# C# While loop logic

Tags: c#, .net

Take a look at this code below, i completely understand what this program is doing but there is one doubt regarding the output of the program on the console.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class program
{
public static void Main()
{
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt");
    string line = "";

    while (line != null)
    {
        line = myReader.ReadLine();
        if(line != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

and the output as follows

[image]

My question is that when i comment off the 'if' statement within the while loop, output is still exactly the same but the cursor moves an extra line down further, and i didn't understand why?

Comment: Move Visual Studio to one side of your screen, your console window to the other side and step through the code with F10 to see why.

Comment: 1) You're not closing the reader. 2) look at `System.IO.File.ReadallLines()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because last readed `line` is `null` and when you have `if` you don't do `Console.WriteLine` and you don't have additional new line.

When you commet it out you don't check if line is not null and if it is `null` you print new line without any other data because `line=null`

Answer (score 2):

This is effectively what you have when you comment out the if statement

```
while (line != null)
{
    line = myReader.ReadLine();        
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

So the extra line you are seeing is `line` being printed when it is in fact **null**.

When the if statement is included, `WriteLine` is not called on the final pass of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(line != null)
```

prints only when string is not NULL

```
  //if(line != null)
```

prints even when string is NULL (The reason why the cursor moved to an extra line down further)

Comment: Use of word "Empty" to explain `null` is likely to confuse things for a beginner as `string.Empty != null`